# Can't connect to Apache Virtualhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I have apache installed fresh on ubuntu 14.04 using Amazon web services. I tried setting up Virtual hosts via apache documentations but i still am not able to connect to the Virtual host.

What i've done on a fresh server is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

And then i've created necessary folders for the virtualhosts:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/public_html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/test.com/public_html
```

Granting permissions..

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/public_html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.com/public_html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

and created demo content for the vhosts

```
nano /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html
```

Creating necessary vhost.conf files: (nearly the same for both hosts)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Enabled config files:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo a2ensite test.com.conf
```

And restarted the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also i've added to /etc/hosts file:

```
54.69.177.170 example.com
54.69.177.170 test.com
```

After all these steps, i am still unable to connect to the virtual host via the specified ServerName. I've made sure all the ports are correct, checked httpd is running and

```
curl -R 54.69.177.170
```

And it returns a html file.

Any help would be appreciated to help me connect to the vhosts.

Comment: Hi Dario, sorry for the silly question, have you checked if you can resolve the name of the virtual host? Do you have it defined somewhere? For instance in your local host file or DNS?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Hello! no i have not checked and i might not have defined it anywhere. I am new to this and i would appreciate it if you could elaborate further. Thank you

Comment: "i am still unable to connect to the virtual host" :- Clarify how you make the connection? Where are you connect the server from? From Internet ? Within the EC2 instance, and method? Did you set up DNS  CNAME?

Comment: @mootmoot I've tried connecting to the virtual host via web browser on the computer i used to set up the server which is connected to the internet. No i have not set up a DNS CNAME. I currently do not have a registered DNS(that requires payment). I would just like to test locally if the vhosts works on my home computer.

Comment: I assume you try to connect to the EC2  from your local PC ?  If so, then you must add `54.69.177.170 example.com` to your local PC  OS hosts file. Without this, when you do  `curl http://www.example.com` , curl will attempt to request the domain from default DNS server.